# stuck at [info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.7.1 (this may take some time) when running sbt in terminal

Tags: scala, sbt

I am executing the sbt command but since the last 2 hrs it has been in the same state and showing "info" [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.16 (this may take some time)..."

Can Someone kindly suggest

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home



sbt -v
[sbt_options] declare -a sbt_options='()'
[process_args] java_version = '8'
# Executing command line:
java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true
-Dsbt.repository.secure=false
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss4M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-Dsbt.script=/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.7.1/libexec/bin/sbt
-jar
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.7.1/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar

[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.7.1  (this may take some time)...


which sbt
/usr/local/bin/sbt


java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_345"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_345-bre_2022_08_04_23_33-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.345-b00, mixed mode)


sbt
[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.7.1  (this may take some time)...


scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.13.8 -- Copyright 2002-2021, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

I Checked The logs It's showing below details in log file.

```
tail -f  $HOME/.sbt/boot/update.log
tail: /Users/rohan.r/.sbt/boot/update.log: No such file or directory
LM00000001:boot rahul1.patidar$ tail -f  $HOME/.sbt/boot/update.log
loadData of org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6 of rootConf=default
default is loaded and no conf to load.  Skip loading
== resolving dependencies org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.16->org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6 [compile->compile]
loadData of org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6 of rootConf=default
default is loaded and no conf to load.  Skip loading
== resolving dependencies org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.16->org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6 [compile->master]
loadData of org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6 of rootConf=default
default is loaded and no conf to load.  Skip loading
== resolving dependencies org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.13.16->org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;1.0.1 [compile->default(compile)]
loadData of org.scala-sbt#launc
```

Comment: 2 hours?! Installing `sbt` should be a matter of 2-3 minutes. You have not mention whether you are using `macOs`, `linux` or `windows`, so I'll just give you the link to the `sbt` [installation] guide (https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Setup.html) and let you choose your platform.

Comment: Could that be network issue on your end? SBT downloads itself (in the project version) when starting.

Comment: The presence of sbt 0.13.16 and Scala 2.10.6 in the log you shared seems puzzling. Are you sure that section of the log is associated with your attempt to use sbt 1.7.1...?